# php root permissions

Tags: php

Is it possible to set root permissions for php script

and manipulate with system folders:

For example:

I want to monitor file changes in specific folder and display it to browser

Comment: sure, you can run it from a root shell, exec() sudo from within php, etc... Question is do you really want to? Running a publicly-accessible script as root is a scary concept, and small bugs could let someone nuke your server from orbit.

Comment: Yet another poor question. You've been here for just about 2 years now; time to read our formatting FAQ and a FAQ on asking good questions.

Comment: no, I need to write script for local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible but not recommended unless your server is internal. In other words, if noone  will have access to your server, you can do that, such as an internal application. exposing this to the world is highly discouraged.

How you can do this is to set your process to sudoers. if you are using this via httpd you can set the httpd process to sudoers.

Comment: You _really_ recommend to give the webserver full root access?!?

Comment: @KingCrunch, I'am use it on local machine for only my own purposes. sudoers config:User_Alias  APACHE = www-data
Cmnd_Alias  HTTHPD = /usr/local/bin/php

APACHE ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: HTTHPD

Comment: @KingCrunch yes i recommend it, what s wrong with doing it if you are not exposing it to the world?

Answer (score 1):

try using sudo http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/

an example of using sudo in php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#56274

Answer (score 1):

You should take the other way round: Make the script readable (and *only* readable) for the user PHP is running under.

Allowing PHP to run with root rights with access from outside (=> browser) is .. just stupid.

Comment: no it s not stupid, you are calling people who allow this stupid as well then , all the OS and sudo designers too. that s wrong.

Comment: @DarthVader: No, not the OS-/sudo-designers, but the guys, that recommend to run a network-accessible service, that allows to execute code, with root rights. Especially the designers of this services recommend _not_ to run it that way.

Comment: if the software designers are aware of this, i m sure they are, they could develop it in such a way to avoid this. but this certainly is not sin. there are times you need it. i dont know why you insisting. it s very easy to ban these services from sudoers and OS, they dont do it, because it s legitimate.

Comment: The developers are not responsible for the way they tools gets used, so why should they "ban" someone? And this case is no one, where you _need_ it. Its just a way to avoid thinking about "real" solutions. I only insist on the fact, that this scenario -- webserver with root rights -- is _never_ a good idea, but on the other side: Its not my server, I don't care.